# Issue merging dataframes in R using POSIXct

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes (per_frame, values) - The first contains POSIXct values for a 24 hour period at 15 minute intervals.

```
periods = as.POSIXct(seq.POSIXt("2019-06-01 04:00:00 UTC","2019-06-02 03:45:00 UTC", by=900))

per_frame = data.frame(Period = periods)
```

The second contains a column for some of the time values above (but not all) and another for 'average value'.

| Period | avg_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-06-01 04:45:00 | 4 |
| 2019-06-01 05:00:00 | 7 |
| 2019-06-01 05:45:00 | 9 |
| 2019-06-01 08:45:00 | 2 |
| 2019-06-01 10:00:00 | 4 |

I want to create a new dataframe that adds the average values where available to the first dataframe, leaving 'missing values' where there aren't any. I thought this could be achieved easily using the below:

```
Combined= merge(per_frame, values, by = "Period", all.x = TRUE)
```

However, the new dataframe it creates has incorrect values for each Period. It is adding values to some time periods that don't have a corresponding average value in the values dataframe. I'm not sure what i'm doing incorrect here?

Comment: Not sure your code for sequence creation is quite correct. Did you mean `seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2019-06-01 04:00:00 UTC"), as.POSIXct("2019-06-02 03:45:00 UTC"), by = 900)` ? Also, your second data frame is provided not in an ideal way. Also, what class is the Period column in the second data frame ? Is it also POSIXct?

Comment: Apologies - I really wasn't sure how to explain my second dataframe without included vast amounts of information. I realised that for (some reason that I don't understand) the time values for the first dataframe are tz UTC whilst they are BST for the second. Hence the mismatch.

Comment: great solution, and interesting problem. For the sake of completeness - for the question, you could have simply sampled 5 rows of your second data frame and output it with `dput(your data frame)` - this way we would have seen the structure and may have been able to reproduce the problem better

Answer (score 1):

Apologies - I realised after some investigation that the timezones used in the two databases were different - hence the mismatch when merging. I'm not actually sure why this happened as i'm using the same data import to generate both the start and end values for the first dataframe and the values for the second. I was able to override it though using the 'tz' value in the as.POSIXct function.